# Python : printing in multiple threads

Tags: python, python-2.7, thread-safety, twisted

I have an implementation of a network system based on Twisted. I noticed that when I run a function (which do some mathematical operations and prints the result) in a new thread, not in the main one, the `print` function causes `Segmentation fault`. Is it possible? Is there an option to avoid that?

Comment: Unlikely, but I guess its possible.  The most obvious issue with `print` in multithreading is that the `stdout` buffer is not threadsafe, and so more than one thread doing `print` can lead to garbled output.  That's not confined to just Python, by the way.

Comment: I've noticed similar issues with Py3 in Cygwin

Comment: But using a lock does not fix it in cygwin

Answer (score 18):

My approach, based on [Bram Cohen's suggestion](https://bramcohen.livejournal.com/70686.html):

Define a global `Lock` variable

```
from threading import Lock

s_print_lock = Lock()
```

Define a function to call `print` with the Lock

```
def s_print(*a, **b):
    """Thread safe print function"""
    with s_print_lock:
        print(*a, **b)
```

Use `s_print` instead of `print` in your threads.

Comment: Why is there a `*a, **b` inside the parameters? does it change how use it from `print()` to `s_print()`?

Comment: @HenriqueBrisola In Python function definition,`*whatever` means positional arguments and `**whatever` means keyword arguments . So this code will just call `print` with all positional arguments and keyword arguments it received. Thus the usage of this `s_print` would be exactly same as `print`.

Comment: I got `print(*a, **b)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a thread lock when you print something in a thread. 
Example:

```
lock = Lock()

lock.acquire() # will block if lock is already held
print("something")
lock.release()
```

In this way the resource(in this case print) will not be used in the same time by multiple threads. 
Using a thread lock is something like focusing the attention on the thread where the lock is acquired.