# Pythn Timer prints in the middle of other prints. Is there some issue with execution order?

Tags: python

I am testing timer function and i am getting some weird prints. My concern is whether this is how code is actualy getting executed, ie function gets run again, while the previous iteration did not finish and thus it can mess up the code. Or it is just print issue and the code itself is fine?

```
import time
import threading
from TestTimerObject import TimerObject

def TestTimers():

    timers = []

    for x in range(10):
        new_timer_obj = TimerObject("Timer" + str(x))
        new_timer_obj.timer = threading.Timer(10.0, TimerFinished, [x])
        new_timer_obj.timer.start()

def TimerFinished(param):
    print("Finished ", param)


TestTimers()
```

Prints:

```
Finished  0
Finished  3
Finished  1
Finished  2
Finished Finished  4
Finished  5Finished  8
Finished  9
 6
Finished  7
```

Hopefully my question is not confusing. In simple terms, why i am getting this mess printed instead of something like this ( order does not matter )

```
Finished 0
Finished 3 
Finished 1 
Finished 2 
Finished 4 
Finished 5 
Finished 8 
Finished 9 
Finished 6 
Finished 7
```

Comment: You need to make your printing "thread-safe". This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356200/python-printing-in-multiple-threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into an issue because the timer is executing in a different thread. You should use the module's semaphore implementation to ensure things are synchronized correctly.

```
import time
import threading
from TestTimerObject import TimerObject

sem = threading.Semaphore(value=1)

def TestTimers():

    timers = []

    for x in range(10):
        new_timer_obj = TimerObject("Timer" + str(x))
        new_timer_obj.timer = threading.Timer(10.0, TimerFinished, [x])
        new_timer_obj.timer.start()

def TimerFinished(param):
    sem.aquire()
    print("Finished ", param)
    sem.release()


TestTimers()
```

Comment: Brilliant, solves the issue, had no idea this exists. Thanks