# Make sure each print is on a newline when threading, indefinitely in python

Tags: python, multithreading, newline, python-multithreading

just a small problem.

I'm using around 6 threads, all of which are printing something every couple of seconds.
Occasionally they print on the same line like this:

```
OUTPUT
OUTPUT
OUTPUTOUTPUT

OUTPUT
OUTPUT
```

This leaves an empty line and a double print as you can see. Is there a way that I can make sure this doesn't happen. I saw something saying:

```
print("OUTPUT", end="\n")
```

This didn't work so I've come back to stack overflow!

Comment: Are you getting any error messages while doing this?

Comment: You can write like this: `print("OUTPUT\n")`

Comment: @MohammadKhoshbin that wouldn't work. It just makes a gap between each print.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python : printing in multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356200/python-printing-in-multiple-threads)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to manage this is to have a wrapper function for print and utilise a threading.Lock. Here's an example:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time

LOCK = Lock()

def doprint(msg):
    with LOCK:
        print(msg)

def athread():
    doprint('Thread is starting')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    doprint('Thread is ending')

threads = []

for _ in range(10):
    t = Thread(target=athread)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

In this way, print() can only ever be invoked by a thread that has successfully acquired the lock